# How to get unique values of 3 data model tables in excel in a single data model table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

The issue is we have 3 databases that contain the names of our suppliers we also have data on those 3 databases that we want to merge into 1 pivot table. In order to do this, we need to get a list of unique items in order to do a many-many relationship match as shown in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286712/how-to-create-a-many-many-relationship-in-excels-data-model

Comment: *we need to get a list of unique items* Copy all 3 data arrays onto a worksheet and use "Remove duplicates".

Comment: Thank you didn't know you could do that. But my concern is if there will be new suppliers that enter the picture. We use auto-refresh on our data models and if there is a missing supplier then it'll be missing in the pivot table I believe

Comment: Can this be done using DAX? I'm very unfamiliar with it

Comment: You need to combine all 3 lists into one list (UNION in SQL terms). Yes, DAX can it. See, for example, [this article](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/dax-query-language-for-power-bi-and-power-pivot/union-appending-of-multiple-tables-in-dax-dax-power-pivot-power-bi/).

Comment: I have no idea how to place it in the `Rows` portion of the pivot table though. I used `Customer:=DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES('TestCur - Invoice'[CustomerID],'TestDR - Invoice'[CustomerID])))` but returns an error

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to work in the Query Editor using the Append feature to combine the data from the 3 databases into one table. All your data modeling and visualisation tasks will be simpler from then on, for example you wont need to build this table.

However if you just want a quick fix using DAX, it would be along these lines:

```
All Customers =
UNION (
    UNION (
        DISTINCT ( 'Invoice1'[CustomerID] ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Invoice2'[CustomerID] )
    ),
    DISTINCT ( 'Invoice3'[CustomerID] )
)
```